# Error while reading a csv file in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
products = pd.read_csv('C:\amazon_baby.csv')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       products = pd.read_csv('C:\amazon_baby.csv')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kvsn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line
>   562, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kvsn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line
>   315, in _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kvsn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line
>   645, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kvsn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line
>   799, in _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kvsn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line
>   1213, in **init**
>       self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 358, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader.**cinit** (pandas\parser.c:3427)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 628, in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:6861)
>
> OSError: File b'C:\x07mazon_baby.csv' does not exist

Comment: add on a backslash to file path like `products = pd.read_csv('C:\\amazon_baby.csv')` because backslash is treated as escape character.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to prefix the string with a @ character. This will make you not need to escape things, but will prevent you from actually adding the quote character you actually used within the string (should be alright in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Grr said, You should not use a single backslash because is a special character. Try:

```
products = pd.read_csv('C:/amazon_baby.csv')
```

This works for Windows, and Unix-like OS. Also, you can use the os module:

```
os.path.join('C:/', 'amazon_baby.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

`products = pd.read_csv(r'C:\amazon_baby.csv')`

or

`products = pd.read_csv('C:\\amazon_baby.csv')`

'\' is the escape character and has to be read as either a raw string or by preceding it with another escape character. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for reference.