# How to read a Time-series data in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, python-3.7

So today, I started with time-series data using Python. First, I tried reading the time series data from a CSV file by using the panda library pd

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error? Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

PS: I am using Python 3.73

```
address = 'C:/Users/Anih John/Desktop/Python-workstation/ff/Superstore-Sales.csv'
Superstore = pd.read_csv(address, index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True)
print(Superstore)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Unable to open 'parsers.pyx': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (c:\users\anih john\desktop\python-workstation\ff\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx)).
```

Comment: Try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337477/6119908 - if it doesn't help, please paste the full traceback (complete error message)

Comment: That doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with the following commands:

```
import pandas as pd
address = 'C:\\Users\\Anih John\\Desktop\\Python-workstation\\ff\\Superstore-Sales.csv'
Superstore = pd.read_csv(address, index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True, engine='python',sep=',')
print(Superstore)
```

EDIT: Or simply using the file in the read_csv function.

```
import pandas as pd
Superstore = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Anih John\\Desktop\\Python-workstation\\ff\\Superstore-Sales.csv', index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True, engine='python',sep=',')
print(Superstore)
```

Comment: Are you able to open the file and edit it? There might be permission issues. Also I forgot to add engine = 'python'. I'll edit it in my answer and try again if you are fully able to open and edit it.