# Can't read csv file on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I can't open a CSV file on Jupyter Notebook. Every time I try to open up, I get this...

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated!

[image: The problem]

Comment: Where are you running the Jupyter notebook?  The error message shows Python is running in Linux, but you are giving a Windows path.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the forward slashes in your path. Change them to double backslashes:

`C:/Users/nsap/desktop...`

to

`C:\\Users\\nsap\\desktop`

Please see this stackoverflow link for more info [Error while reading a csv file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38336501/13700906)